# Laravel 5.1 bcrypt and login

Tags: php, laravel, bcrypt

When I'm registering a new user in the Laravel framework, I'm currently doing it like this,

```
// Creating a new user
$user = new User;
$user->firstname = $data['firstname'];
$user->lastname = $data['lastname'];
$user->email = $data['email'];
$user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
$user->save();
```

This works great, and I am able to login to the application. However, I want the user to have an option to change their passwords in their settings page. Doing this, i used the same technique, using

```
$newPass = bcrypt($response->new_password);
```

and updating the user field. However, after doing this, I'm not able to login? I'm using the built in authentication service in laravel for the registration/login.

What am I doing wrong here? and should i do it another way?

I also tried to bcrypt my current password, and i got an completely different hash than the one stored in the database.

This so confusing..

Updated with controller code,

```
// Validation
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'email',
    'password' => 'min:8|confirmed',
    'current_password' => 'required',
]);

// Getting the user ID
$userId = Auth::id();

// Dummy hack check, change later.
if(!Auth::attempt(['id' => $userId, 'password' => $request->current_password]))
{
    return redirect('settings')->with('alert','current password is wrong.');
}

// Everything is validated and ok to proceed
if($request->email)
{
    $data['email'] = $request->email;
}

if($request->password)
{
    $data['password'] = bcrypt("helloworld");
}

$user = User::where('id',$userId)->update($data);

dd($data);
```

Dump data for the inputs,

```
  +request: ParameterBag {#40 ▼
    #parameters: array:5 [▼
      "_token" => "JQIIuCjiKQmbK0X5zCM6czYD1vIoh4PGjLO4qrFm"
      "email" => "testing@gmail.com"
      "password" => "thisisnewpass"
      "password_confirmation" => "thisisnewpass"
      "current_password" => "helloworld"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Did you save the user after setting the new password?

Comment: Yes, the database get's updated.

Comment: Is the user still logged in from before you changed the password?

Comment: When the user changes the password, they are still logged in, yes. If i logout myself, and try to login again, it keeps saying wrong password, and even my old password won't work.

Comment: Does `$response->new_password` actually exists and is it set to what you expect it to be? Try hashing a plain string and see if you can login with that string.

Comment: Ok, i tried to hash a plaintext, and that worked. Now, I'm not sure why my password from the form input is not hashing correctly.. However, when i changed the password from a plain text, i also got logged out.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually getting the input from the form? Print `$response->new_password` before you hash it and see if it has any extra white space.

Comment: Actually, just post your entire function that handles the password change request. Let me look at the code, or we'll be here asking questions forever.

Comment: I've updated the code with controller and dump

Answer (score 0):

This code is closer to how Laravel handles resetting a user's password internally. Give it a try.

```php
// Getting the User
$user = Auth::user(); // Gets the currently logged in User
$credentials = [
    'id' => $user->id,
    'password' => $request->input('current_password')
];

// Make sure current password is correct
if (!Auth::validate($credentials)) { // Checks the User's credentials
    return redirect('settings')->with('alert','current password is wrong.');
}

// Change the password
if ($request->has('password')) {
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
}

// Save any changes
$user->save();
```

It looks like you're using the same form to update the User's email address too, so update the code to fit your needs.

Comment: This is the exact same as I'm doing it, by using bcrypt, however, something is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the password in an new variable seems to fix the issue (not sure why?) however, this is the code that made everything work,

```
// Validation
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'email',
    'password' => 'min:8|confirmed',
    'current_password' => 'required',
]);

// Getting the user ID
$userId = Auth::id();
$newPassword = $request->password;

// Dummy hack check, change later.
if(!Auth::attempt(['id' => $userId, 'password' => $request->current_password]))
{
    return redirect('settings')->with('alert','Wrong password.');
}

// Everything is validated and ok to proceed
if($request->email)
{
    $data['email'] = $request->email;
}

if($request->password)
{
    $data['password'] = bcrypt($newPassword);
}

// Getting, and checking if the current password is corrent.
$user = User::where('id',$userId)->update($data);

echo $newPassword . "<br><br>";

dd($data);
```

If there is any explanations that i don't see, please let me know why. However, it's working now.

Comment: If you copy and paste the exact `$request->password` from your code above into the `bcrypt()` call, does it break again?

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel in year 2017, this is how we roll:

```
//create a setter method in your controller

public function setPasswordAttribute( $password ) {
    if ( $password !== null ) {
        if ( is_null(request()->bcrypt) ) {
            $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
        } else {
            $this->attributes['password'] = $password;
        }
    }
}
```

Check [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/how-to-hash-user-input-password-when-using-form-validation-in-form-request-laravel-5) link they all are talking about placing it in model but it works inside my own controller.

Comment: This bad code. You shouldn't silently do nothing if `$password` argument comes as `null`.